# Full LaTeX on tablet devices

Tags: ipad, tablet, android

I would like to know if there is a tablet device (iPad, Nexus...etc) on which one can install a full LaTeX environment. By "full", I mean that:

- One can produce (compile successfully) from any `.tex` file the dvi or PDF file.
- If any package is missing, one can install it manually (or better automatically, as MikTeX).

After searching on Google, it seems to me that there is no such tablet device. Most of the LaTeX editors on tablet device require an internet connection (i.e., they compile `.tex` on a server). In [this post](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/i-tex-therefore-ipad-reloaded/), the author mentioned that [TeX Writer (UK store)](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tex-writer-latex-editor-compiler/id552717222?mt=8) (for iOS) doesn't require an internet connection.
But it looks like it is just a LaTeX editor. I don't know how it works with LaTeX. (Does it provide a mini-LaTeX environment or something else?).

p.s. Of course I don't want to type `.tex` file on a tablet device for a long time. But sometimes I may need to modify an existing `.tex` file (e.g., when I find some errors in my paper).

Comment: TeX Writer compiles the files on the iPad, and so does TexPad (which also has the capability to send the send a file to a server to be compiled remotely)

Comment: @Guido, do you know Tex Writer and TexPad work with LaTex? I mean they provide a (mini or full) LaTex environment or the users need to install LaTex distribution themselves?

Comment: They work with LaTeX and they have several packages preinstalled, and you can install further package. They are usable.

Comment: Earlier today I was contemplating putting this on my android tablet, if you have debian linux you could install the arm texlive distribution... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dyndns.sven_ola.debian_kit&hl=en

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Texpad developers here.  The answer is yes - you can do this on the iPad with Texpad. Texpad for iOS has had a built in LaTeX typesetter, no internet connection required. Most commonly used LaTeX packages are now included, and we expand the distribution with every update (9 updates in the past three months), and it is now so good that one user edits LaTeX on his Mac and typesets on his iPhone because the distribution is leaner, simpler and faster.

PGF drivers are underway right now and the update with local TikZ/Beamer typesetting should be ready for download in February.

In addition to the onboard typesetter, we still provide free cloud typesetting servers with the entirety of TexLive 2012 installed. If you have any further questions, email us at support@vallettaventures.com.

**UPDATE:** Tikz and beamer are now working in 1.5 and later releases. In addition all the fonts plus latex and bibtex packages are downloadable using the **Bundle Manager** in Texpad now: http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-ios/latex-bundle-manager-on-texpad-ios . Check it out and let us have your feedback via 'Contact Us' form on http://texpadapp.com .

Comment: Does the logicool keyboard for ipad works with Texpad?

Comment: Hi VV, I am very interested in being able to use latex on my ipad and would be willing to pay the price for a good app. Unfortunately all the apps I tried suck. Can you please update your answer to tell us, what your app does well, what it is not so good at (currently) and what you plan on improving in the near future? Thanks

Comment: Can texpad work with dropbox files?

Comment: I have found that some latex package are not up-to-date (eg. siunitx,...)
Texpad still uses old version of siunitx that use "\SI{}{}" for unit. Newest version use "\qty{}{}".

The question is how to update package of texpad on MacOS/iPadOS?

Answer (score 16):

*This answer only concerns the iPad.*

I'm not going to reproduce my blog post (already linked in the question) as it is still relevant.  I'll highlight a couple of points directly related to your question.

> One can produce (compile successfully) from any `.tex` file the dvi or PDF file.

Taking the "any" at face value, the answer is "Not yet".  There are (at time of writing) two iPad applications that can compile a tex document on the iPad without needing internet connectivity.  One of those is TeX Writer, the other is TeXPad.  Neither can compile *any* tex document.  TeX Writer currently uses unadulterated TeX, meaning that it doesn't have the e-TeX extensions and produces DVI (which it then converts to PDF).  So anything that uses the e-TeX extensions does not currently compile (nor XeTeX nor LuaTeX).  TeXPad is based on KerTeX about which I know very little.

But with that taken into account - and with the knowledge that they are both in their infancy - it is now possible to compile documents directly on an iPad with no internet connection.  Both come with the LaTeX format, TeX Writer also includes a plain TeX format.

> If any package is missing, one can install it manually (or better automatically, as MikTeX).

Both of these applications allow installation of packages, neither is automatic.

Answer (score 12):

Just have a look here: [TexPortal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lah.texportal&hl=de). This is an App for Android which runs on my Nexus 7 without the need for root and an internet connection. I didn't try to compile very complex documents but for some of my simple business letters it works perfectly. Keep in mind this is only the compiler not an editor! The sources and the installation guide you can find here: https://github.com/anhoavu/TeXPortal.

Comment: TeXPortal seems not to exist anymore.

Answer (score 9):

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer of VerbTeX)

**[VerbTeX](https://www.verbosus.com/)** may be an alternative. It's available for Android, iOS and Windows 8. It uses a full (and up-to-date) TexLive distribution in the background to generate PDF. So there's generally no need to install any missing packages (since no packages are missing). If you create custom packages you can also simply upload and use them.

Comment: I really can't seem to get the dropbox integration  of verbtex to work

Comment: @TejasShetty After you Link to Dropbox VerbTeX will automatically synchronize all your Local Mode projects in the background (around once per minute or so). No need to manually click a button or something similar.

Comment: Sadly, it still fails. How can I contact you? @peter

Comment: @TejasShetty You can contact us via office@verbosus.com

Answer (score 5):

TeX Writer on both iOS and Android is a LaTeX editor and compiler for tablets. It has a minimal distribution. Additional packages can be downloaded automatically on demand.

iOS App Store:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tex-writer-latex-editor-compiler/id552717222?mt=8

Google play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.litchie.texwriter

Answer (score 4):

This may be be a kludge, but if you have a rooted Android device, one can dual-boot various flavors of Linux (there are apps that will help in the installation process). Inside Linux, one can install texlive and compile anything you would like.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an app to meet this need on my Android. It can also output PDFs. It renders TeX in real time.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TeXEditor.TeXEditor_full