# LEdBeta(0.53)Build(6501)Std My problem with it

Tags: led-editor

I have downloaded LEdBeta(0.53)Build(6501)Std and the program didn't need any setup. It work directly. The problem is I get this message when I open it.
The DVI file does not exist.
Also, I can't open the pdf file and it give me this message
'dvipdfm.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
07-09-2015 18:30:01: STOP
How can I solve this problems?

Answer (score 1):

The last updated version of LEd is dated 2009-10-9 and it doesn't seem to support the latest features of TeX Live or MiKTeX.

You of course need a TeX distribution (TeX Live or MiKTeX), see [Latex distributions. What are their main differences?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239199/latex-distributions-what-are-their-main-differences/239204#239204)

See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) for suggestions about a better text editor or front end for LaTeX.

You should also have a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) for other basic information.