# Make Texmaker like Overleaf

Tags: texmaker, overleaf, overleaf-toolkit

I've used texmaker primarily first, but I switched to overleaf and liked it a lot better.
Overleaf lets me tabulate mutliple lines by highlighting them and pressing tab, lets me swap code between lines by pressing option + arrow key (the current selected line gets swapped in the direction of the arrow key), and I can toggle comment one line or multiple lines by pressing command+/ (I'm on a mac). Overleaf allows for the compiled pdf and latex code to be in seperate windows as well, and math mode in `\begin{align}` or `\begin{equation}` makes the code to be black and blue, which IMO is better to look at than green for all environments.

However, I don't like the fact that I have to be online to use overleaf, and would much prefer to compile the code on my computer. But as far as I am aware, there is no way to configure all the features mentioned above to texmaker. Is there any other LaTeX text editor that has these features and keyboard shortcuts, or is it possible to configure texmaker to have all these features?

Comment: This post mentions the most common Latex distributions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239199/latex-distributions-what-are-their-main-differences . Check out their editors capabilities. // However, if you focus only on Editors, there's a plethora out there from programmers world, which have similar preferences as you do. So have a look there. // Latex compile will certainly work from the command line or terminal, and with some back and forth and luck might be integrated into such editors (IDE's). // Or you do a combo: IDE (edits) + Texmaker (compile) or similar.

Comment: If you have a local webserver (WAMP, XAMP, UniController etc.), you can install your overleaf locally on your localhost: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf . How close is this state to the online version? No idea.

Comment: You don't have to use TeXmaker, you know? My editor of choice lets me do all these things and then some, all configured precisely the way I like it. Sounds like you just need a better editor.

Comment: @Ingmar I guess the OP wants to know which editor you use, because they are looking for an editor that has these features (or can be configured to have them). That is sort of a recommendation question which is off-topic, but maybe you can help them out in a comment.

Comment: Right. That said, any halfway decent editor should be able to come close, at least. Personally, I am partial to Sublime Text.