# I can't view the pdf preview of my tex file

Tags: pdftex, vscode

I am currently using LaTeX Workshop in VSCode and each time I attempt to view the pdf preview of my tex file I receive the following message in the bottom right.

> BlockquoteCannot view file PDF file. File not found: file:///c%3A/Users/Tony%20Zhang/OneDrive/Senior-Year/Math/Math%20IA/Outline.pdf

The output is the following:

```
[21:26:57] Current workspace folders: ["file:///c:/Users/Tony Zhang/OneDrive/Senior-Year/Math/Math IA"]
[21:26:57] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\Tony Zhang\OneDrive\Senior-Year\Math\Math IA\Outline.tex
[21:26:57] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\Tony Zhang\OneDrive\Senior-Year\Math\Math IA\Outline.tex
[21:26:57] Cannot find PDF file file:///c%3A/Users/Tony%20Zhang/OneDrive/Senior-Year/Math/Math%20IA/Outline.pdf
```

Can someone help me out? This is my first time trying LaTex in VScode and was following this [website](https://mathjiajia.github.io/vscode-and-latex/#step-3-install--configure-latex-workshop).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does your local TeX installation work if you call it e.g. via the console?

Comment: How could I do it that via that console?

Comment: Just type in `tex`, enter, and look what happens. If you have a proper TeX installation on your machine, there should be some kind of relevant output.

Comment: So I but tex in windows powershell and it said that the term 'tex' was not recognized. Were you referring to something else? I'm sorry I'm really new to this.

Comment: It seems that you did not install TeX then. Note that the LaTeX Workshop extension is only a tool to help you code (La)TeX files, but in order to compile them (and shw the resulting PDF as output) you need to have TeX installed on your machine.

Comment: Actually, I don't know this LaTeX Workshop extension. I assume that it looks for an existing PDF in the same directory. Such an PDF only exists after you compiled your .tex file at least once. I can only guess what is going on.

Comment: You can ease your pain once you install a common Latex distribution, like MikTex (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239199/latex-distributions-what-are-their-main-differences) . Though you may succeed in getting VScode work with Latex, those other IDEs are designed to easy your pain. // After that you may see easier what's missing in your current attempt.