# Problem with aligning text but not equations

Tags: alignment

```
\begin{align*}
\\ \text{Let } arcsin(x) & = \theta
\\\text{But } \theta \text{ is a function of x so we can write }
\\ arcsin(x) & = \theta(x)
\\ x & = sin(\theta(x))
\\ \frac{d}{dx}x & = \frac{d}{dx}sin(\theta(x))

\\ \text{Imagine f(x) = sin(x) and g(x) = } \theta(x).
\\ \text{Thus, f'(g(x))g'(x) = cos(} \theta(x))\theta'(x).
\\\text{So overall, you differentiated sin(} \theta) \text{ with respect to } \theta.
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I wrote the above in Notion. I managed to align all my equations however, my text is not aligned. I am struggling to fix this.

I am new to LaTeX and to this community so I apologise if my question is in the wrong format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thank you Mico! :)

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please upgrade your code, e.g. by following this checklist? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 Thank you

Comment: Off-topic: `f'(g(x))g'(x) = cos` really ought to be processed in math mode, not text mode. The fact that no syntax error happens to be thrown in no way implies that it's appropriate to render `f'(g(x))g'(x) = cos` in text mode.

Comment: FWIW: your text is aligned: there's an implicit `&` at the end of your `\text` lines, and all `&` vertically align just left of the `=`.

Comment: You could always use \hspace{} to horizontally align each line (negative lengths are allowed).  Also, there is an \arcsin in math mode which makes the text plain rather than italic.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take the first two lines and the last line out of the `align*` environment entirely and place one of the intermediate lines in an `\intertext` wrapper. (BTW, I'm addressing only the typesetting issues, *not* the mathematics involved. Hence, I'm not going to comment on `\frac{d}{dx}x`.)

Oh, by all means please write `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\arcsin` rather than just `sin`, `cos`, and `arcsin`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env. and '\intertext' macro
\begin{document}

\noindent
Let $\arcsin(x) = \theta$. Because $\theta$ is a function of $x$, we can write
\begin{align*}
\arcsin(x) &= \theta(x) \\ 
x &= \sin(\theta(x)) \\ 
\frac{d}{dx}x &= \frac{d}{dx}\sin(\theta(x))\,.\\ 
\intertext{Put $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = \theta(x)$. Thus}
f'(g(x))g'(x) &= \cos(\theta(x))\theta'(x).
\end{align*}
So overall, you differentiated $\sin(\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works in overleaf but not in Notion.

Comment: @user22752014 - Notion is based on Katex, right? Katex syntax superficially looks like LaTeX syntax, but the engines that underlie Katex and LaTeX are completely different. Katex-related issues are [off-topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648196/5001) for the TeX.SE site. Note that the Overleaf site provides "real LaTeX", *not* Katex.