# Latex software for Android Tablet

Tags: texlive, android, tablet

I've been trying, in vain, to search the forums for real solutions to using `LaTeX` on an Android Tablet (Possibly because there is no real solution).

My question is basically, how much of the standard LaTeX features can be carried out, using the LaTeX software currently avaliable (VerbTeX, LiveTeX as far as i googled).

Currently i am using TeXmaker + MiKTeX on my laptop. What I want to be able to do, is open all the same files on my tablet, create new files and edit old files, as well as being able to install the packages I am also using laptop - On my new tablet. (Document classes, `.sty`, `.tex`, `.cls`, `.bib` etc.)

Are there any apps via the android playstore currently available that will make this possible ?

If this has already been discussed over and over, I apologize for not being able to find it.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/

Comment: Duplicates: [Full LaTeX on tablet devices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83114) and [How to install TeX on android phones?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87520)