# Is there any way to use LaTeX on mobile phones?

Tags: android

Could LaTeX be used to take notes in class on 5'5 smart phone well? Is there some application or method to use LaTeX on phones?

Comment: Does "ShareLaTeX" work for you? It is an online tool (not downloaded). Look it up.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83114/117050

Comment: and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87520/117050

Comment: Verbosus: https://www.verbosus.com/latex.html has a free app that allows creating 4 projects at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in typing, then just use a text editor. If you want something a bit more, you can get vimtouch (I used to use it religiously).

It's advised, though, to use hacker's keyboard, b/c other keyboards won't have the backslash and such.

If you're really into it, and you're rooted, you can rule a full blown linux distro. More details can be given if you're interested (I'm on mobile now).